# Angular ng-repeat alias in the repeat expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given a template like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
  {{user.firstName}}
</li>
```

Is there any way to "alias" the "user" so I can do this instead:

```
<li ng-repeat="SOME MAGIC HERE MAYBE?">
  {{firstName}}
</li>
```

So that I don't need to type the "user." prefix for each expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the script to put into controller

```
$scope.scopify = function(scope, obj){
    for (var a in obj) {
        scope[a] = obj[a];
    }        
}
```

Then call it like this

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-init="scopify(this,user)">  
  {{firstName}}
</li>
```